# How to import the list of value from table to string line

Tags: java, arrays, string, netbeans, jtable

i have create a table in java which has one column and many rows, i also have a String line which i want to import the list of my value inside of my string line:
i have run my code and the result is this:

```
begining of line [item1] end of line
begining of line [item2] end of line
begining of line [item3] end of line
begining of line [item4] end of line
```

but i am looking for the result like this:

```
begining of line    [item1], 
                    [item2], 
                    [item3],
                    [item4]   end of line
```

[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHKqy.png)

this is my code:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
for (int i=0;i<model.getRowCount();i++){
        String b = " ["+(jTable1.getValueAt(i,0)).toString()+"] ";

        String text="begining of line"+b+"end of line";
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

i am new in java thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code :

```
    String beginning= "beginning of line";
    String emptySpaces = new String(new char[begining.length()]).replace("\0", " "); // Create empty spaces with the same length of the begining sentence
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        final String first = (i == 0) ? begining : emptySpaces;
        builder.append(first).append(" [").append(jTable1.getValueAt(i,0).toString()).append("]");
        final String last = (i == model.getRowCount() - 1) ? " end of line" : ",\n";
        builder.append(last);
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

I used string builder to avoid String creation performance issues

it will show you the expected result

```
beginning of line [item1],
                  [item2],
                  [item3],
                  [item4],
                  [item5] end of line
```

Comment: thanks for answer, it seems what i want, but i don't know why  " list.get " and " list.size " have red underline and i cant import the library for that.do you have an idea

Comment: I just edited the code, I used a list in my local and forgot to edit the list with your model, you can try the code now

Answer (score 0):

You can start text before for loop with value "begining of line" in your for loop add item to text and after the for loop add "end of line" to it. You can use the + operator to concatenate string or if you want to be efficient you can use Stringbuilder class.

Comment: i have move the two text before and after the loop but this is not run, because the error said that can not find symbol:(variable b): do you know how to solve this?                                                          `DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
String a="begining of line"
for (int i=0;i<model.getRowCount();i++){
        String b = " ["+(jTable1.getValueAt(i,0)).toString()+"] ";
}
String b="end of line"

System.out.println(a+b+c);`